# How do you restore a doughnut polygon that has been turned into a simple polygon, using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, holes

I've received a `.shp` file which has a hole in the middle, I'm trying to style it nicely so I don't want the outline that cuts from the "inner" to "outer" polygon. I quote inner and outer aren't actually inner and outer but are both part of the same outline. The cut is probably was originally made by the originator to have a hole in the middle of a simple polygon.

[image]

How do I using QGIS2 or its plugins change the polygon to a complex one, remove the "cut" edges marked by the arrow and correctly make the inner and outer boundaries for it?

Comment: Is that the only one? Draw a new one covering the hole and then merge them

Comment: Yes thankfully for this case there is only one. I'd tried buffering with zero width and remove slivers etc... none of those worked. duplicating the shape then deleting the outer ring nodes than the inner ring on the other shape, before apply a difference operation works. Now I'm just curious if there is a simpler approach to this?

Comment: Like i said "Draw a new one covering the hole and then merge them"